# How to get the last week's date using the new Date() method in the local format - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the last week data and for that I'm trying to get the last week date from today's date:

```
var today = new Date(); // Fri May 22 2015 11:05:05 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

What im trying to get is: `Fri May 15 2015 11:05:05 GMT-0700 (PDT)`. Any ideas how can i achieve that???
Thank!

Comment: `date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Times are compared in milliseconds. So you want to subtract the number of milliseconds from today.

Convert the number of days to the number of milliseconds and store it in a new variable. We will then subtract this value from the current date.

```
var today = new Date("2015/05/22");
var msPerWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
var lastWeek= new Date(today.getTime() - msPerWeek);

alert(lastWeek)
```

Result

```
Fri May 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT -0500(Central Daylight Time)
```